# Custom attribute requiring double click (featherlight lightbox)

Tags: jquery, featherlight.js

So, here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5e9e2k6y/5/):

Here is the link to the plugin ([featherlight lightbox](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight#support))

The issue is that using the default targetAttr (which is `data-featherlight`), it works with only one click.

However, with a custom targetAttr (such as `data-single` in this example), I have to click twice before the lightbox opens.

Could someone help me out why it is doing it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

featherlight() has a build-in click trigger so you just need to call the plugin directly:

```
jQuery('.something_else').featherlight({
       targetAttr: 'data-single',                  
});
```

see: https://jsfiddle.net/5e9e2k6y/9/

Answer (score 1):

`$('selector').featherlight()` (or using `data-featherlight`) is for binding, like `$('selector').click( function() {...} )`.

`$.featherlight(...)` is for triggering, like `$('selector').click()`

So, bind on click and trigger, or bind via `$('...').featherlight`, but don't bind on click and then bind in that handler, like you're doing now.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. I will give that a try. ☺ thanks