# Bind on Click and Trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682521/custom-attribute-requiring-double-click-featherlight-lightbox) which has this [jsfiddles](https://jsfiddle.net/5e9e2k6y/5/).

The answer was the following as below:

> $('selector').featherlight() (or using data-featherlight) is for
>   binding, like $('selector').click( function() {...} ).
>
> $.featherlight(...) is for triggering, like $('selector').click()
>
> So, bind on click and trigger, or bind via $('...').featherlight, but
>   don't bind on click and then bind in that handler, like you're doing
>   now.

I am having the same issue but I don't know how to `bind on click and trigger` like the answer.

So, if this is the js code (original code) then how would you `bind on click and trigger`?

```
jQuery('.something_else').click(function(e) {           
    jQuery('.something_else').featherlight({
                targetAttr: 'data-single',                  
            });                             
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
jQuery('.something_else').featherlight({
                    targetAttr: 'data-single',                  
                });
```

jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/5e9e2k6y/9/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/5e9e2k6y/7/  but i still have to click it twice. =(

Comment: Thank you for the updated version. What should I do if I need to include a click function? Here is an example (last button) https://jsfiddle.net/5e9e2k6y/10/.  I need the click function in order to make a variable and target specific button.

Comment: Thank you! =) you are the best!